# How to migrate data to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am in need of a script that Updates the rows on a table from another table based on an ID and after that it deletes the from the second table the data it  copied.

This are the tables I have

```
Documents
--------
DocumentID(PK)
RealFileName
FileName

ImageDocuments
--------------
ImageDocumentId(PK)
DocumentId(FK)
OriginalFileName
StorageFileName
```

Mapping beetween the two tables is One to One.

At the moment I have the script that updates the table but I do not know how to proceed to delete the values from documents table.This is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[ImageDocuments]
SET [dbo].[ImageDocuments].[OriginalFileName] = d.FileName,
    [dbo].[ImageDocuments].[StorageFileName] = d.RealName
FROM [dbo].[ImageDocuments] as fu, 
     [dbo].[Documents] as d
WHERE fu.DocumentID = d.DocumentID
```

How can I delete from the documents table the rows that were added to the ImageDocuments table?

**UPDATE**
I create a delete query can anyone please validate if this will work corectly:

```
DELETE [dbo].[Documents]
FROM [dbo].[ImageDocuments] as fu
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Documents] as d ON d.DocumentID = fu.DocumentID
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you have?

Comment: Sql-Server Enterprise Edition 2010

Comment: There is no such version of SQL Server.

Comment: This is what it says on properties when I click on the database in SSMS : Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition (64-bit)

Comment: But there is no 2010 as mentioned in your previous comment.

Comment: for version just type `Select @@version` in your query analyzer and for query i think your query will work and it is the another version what i gave in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[ImageDocuments]
SET [dbo].[ImageDocuments].[OriginalFileName] = d.FileName,
    [dbo].[ImageDocuments].[StorageFileName] = d.RealName
OUTPUT INSERTED.ImageDocumentId
INTO @Ids
FROM [dbo].[ImageDocuments] as fu, 
     [dbo].[Documents] as d
WHERE fu.DocumentID = d.DocumentID;

DELETE FROM Documents
WHERE DocumentID IN (SELECT ImageDocumentId FROM @IDs);
```

Comment: i have not downvoted your answer .. but a small question will SQL server inserts all the updated ids in INSERTED table or INSERTED is for only insert statements ??

Comment: You will have IDs of affected rows. [OUTPUT Clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(v=sql.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

As you already copied all rows  in ImageDocuments you can safely delete all the DocumentID in Documents

```
    UPDATE [dbo].[ImageDocuments]
    SET [dbo].[ImageDocuments].[OriginalFileName] = d.FileName,
        [dbo].[ImageDocuments].[StorageFileName] = d.RealName
    FROM [dbo].[ImageDocuments] as fu, 
         [dbo].[Documents] as d
    WHERE fu.DocumentID = d.DocumentID;

    Delete From Documents where Documents.DocumentID in 
(Select ImageDocuments.DocumentID from ImageDocuments);
```

Comment: I do not want to delete all the documents because there are more tables that are related to the Documents table I only want to delete the ones that were copied

Answer (score 0):

I would use a temporary table to store the matching records in both tables. Afterwards, by using that temporary table, you could delete the data those you already used in other table.

Such as;

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (MatchingId INT)
INSERT INTO @Table 
SELECT DocumentID FROM [ImageDocuments] ImgDoc 
INNER JOIN [Documents] doc 
    ON ImgDoc.DocumentID = doc.DocumentID

UPDATE [dbo].[ImageDocuments]
SET [dbo].[ImageDocuments].[OriginalFileName] = d.FileName,
    [dbo].[ImageDocuments].[StorageFileName] = d.RealName
FROM [dbo].[ImageDocuments] as fu, 
     [dbo].[Documents] as d
WHERE fu.DocumentID = d.DocumentID

DELETE FROM DocumentID WHERE DocumentID IN 
(SELECT DocumentID FROM @Table )
```